# Is it OK to direct questions about a mobile GIS system that would otherwise require their own site here?

Tags: discussion

Just checking on meta first, because it's polite.

My "day job" (besides being a diamond over on RPG) is helping to develop an archaeology data collection application (http://fedarch.org). We've entered the "how do we support the users?" phase of things.

We, obviously, plan to have standard real documentation (a wiki), community support, etc. but as there is a significant technical component to the app, would it be appropriate to direct fiddly technical questions here?

Comment: This related Meta question http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3180/should-we-allow-the-site-to-become-a-support-forum-for-a-particular-software see Robert Cartaino♦'s answer.

Comment: Fantastic, that is exactly what I was hoping for. When we get our help routing set up, I'll linky. Close as dupe?

Comment: Closed as a duplicate--but +1 for asking!